# OnClick dosen't exist in Override method list

Tags: android-studio, sdk, overriding, android-view, onclicklistener

Hello everybody I want to add OnClick method in this [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yOt0.jpg)

thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class from which you opened the "override methods" dialog from should implement the `View.OnClickListener`. It should then be in that list.

Comment: I want to add this

Comment: What do you mean with "I want to add this". Do you mean you don't know how to implement it? Do it like this: `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener { // class data }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onclickname(View v){
   ...
}
```

Comment: You should add it after onCreate void.